# Simple Youtube + Htaccess Redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, youtube, forward

website.com/yt/MGEPkLPGB6E

would forward to

youtube.com/watch?v=MGEPkLPGB6E

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in a .htaccess file, or in your Apache's configuration, should do the trick :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^yt/(.*)$   http://youtube.com/watch?v=$1
```

Of course, this is if the `mod_rewrite` module is enabled.